# Configuring Tomee to allow WebSphere JNDI Lookups

Tags: ejb-3.0, jndi, apache-tomee

We are currently developing an application intended for deployment on a WebSphere server. The application should use an in-house Service Provider, that provides access to services implemented as remote EJBs. The Service Provider bean has some hard-coded jndi-names to use.

Now during development we are using Tomee and in general all is working nicely. All except one thing:
The ServiceProvider does a jndi-lookup of "cell/persistent/configService". Now I tried to create a mock ear that contains mock EJBs for these services. I am able to deploy them, and I am able to access them from the application using jndi-names like: "java:global/framework-mock-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/framework-mock-impl/ConfigServiceMock" but it seems to be impossible to access them using a jndi lookup of: "cell/persistent/configService" ... now I added an openejb-jar.xml file to my mock implementation containing:

```
<openejb-jar>
    <ejb-deployment ejb-name="ConfigServiceMock">
        <jndi name="cell/persistent/configService"
              interface="de.thecompany.common.services.config.ConfigService"/>
    </ejb-deployment>
</openejb-jar>
```

And I can see during startup, that the bean seems to be registered correctly under that name:

```
INFORMATION: Jndi(name=cell/persistent/configService) --> Ejb(deployment-id=ConfigServiceMock)
```

But I have now idea how to make the other ear be able to access this bean using that name.

The Service Provider part is given and we are not able to change this at all, so please don't suggest to change the hard-coded jndi names. We surely would like to do so, but are not able to change anything.

Comment: Try with {deploymentId}/{interfaceClassName} as the jndi name and see if you can lookup the bean

Comment: Yes that does work, but as I wrote in my post, I am unable to change the names as they are part of a compiled library that I have to use.

Comment: I meant Lookup using that name in your client/yourEJB. Where are you doing the lookup?

Comment: Well I made Tomee bind the EJB to exactly that name (As you can see it outputs the binding), but when looking up the bean using JNDI the InitialContext seems to only be able to find beans with the prefix "java:". But I found a solution that worked and will post that as an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... to I wasted quite some time on this. Until I finally came up with a solution. Instead of configuring Tomee and OpenEJB to find my beans, I hijacked the InitialContext and rewrote my queries.

```
package de.mycompany.mock.tomee;

import org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class MycompanyNamingContextFactory extends javaURLContextFactory {

    private static Context initialContext;

    @Override
    public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable environment) throws NamingException {
        if(initialContext == null) {
            Hashtable childEnv = (Hashtable) environment.clone();
            childEnv.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
            initialContext = new MycompanyInitialContext(childEnv);
        }
        return initialContext;
    }

}
```

By setting the system property

```
java.naming.factory.initial=de.mycompany.mock.tomee.MycompanyNamingContextFactory
```

I was able to inject my MycompanyInitialContext context implementation:

```
package de.mycompany.mock.tomee;

import org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext;
import org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.NameNode;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class MycomanyInitialContext extends IvmContext {

    public MycomanyInitialContext(Hashtable<String, Object> environment) throws NamingException {
        super(environment);
    }

    @Override
    public Object lookup(String compositName) throws NamingException {
        if("cell/persistent/configService".equals(compositName)) {
            return super.lookup("java:global/mycompany-mock-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mycompany-mock-impl/ConfigServiceMock");
        }
        if("cell/persistent/authorizationService".equals(compositName)) {
            Object obj = super.lookup("java:global/mycompany-mock-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mycompany-mock-impl/AuthServiceMock");
            return obj;
        }
        return super.lookup(compositName);
    }

}
```

I know this is not pretty and if anyone has an idea how do make this easier and prettier, I'm all ears and this solution seems to work. As it's only intended on simulating production services during development, this hack doesn't induce any nightmares for me. Just thought I'd post it, just in case someone else stumbles over something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is coming a few years after the question, but a simpler solution would be to simply set the system property as follows (say in catalina.properties):

```
java.naming.initial.factory=org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBInitialContextFactory
```

This allows you to lookup the ejb by the name you set, and the one that shows in tomee logs during startup, eg your 'cell/persistent/configService' from

```
INFORMATION: Jndi(name=cell/persistent/configService) --> Ejb(deployment-id=ConfigServiceMock)
```

With the system property set you can lookup the ejb the way you would want

```
final Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.lookup("cell/persistent/configService")
```

The OpenEJBInitialContextFactory allows access to local EJBs as well as container resources.

If you didn't want to set the system property (as it would affect all applications in the tomee) you could still use the factory setting it the 'standard' way:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.core.OpenEJBInitialContextFactory");
    final Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
    ctx.lookup("cell/persistent/configService");
```

And of course you could still look them up using the global "java:global/" as well with that factory.